# How to render react.js content from draft.js json

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, draftjs

Let's say i have draft.js editor and after editing is finished i preserved result to dataBase. I have two approaches: to save result as html string or as json object. When i use a html string from dataBase it's easy to render it using dangerouslySetInnerHTML. But how to use json object that is produced by convertToRaw draft.js method if i want to display this content not in the  but in **some other component**? I know that i can use , but i'm not sure that this is optimize approach to show lot of  on page
An example of json object from draft.js

```
{
   blocks: [
      {
         data: {},
         depth: 0,
         entityRanges: [],
         inlineStyleRanges: [],
         key: "f25a2",
         text: "Styled string, ",
         type: "unstyled"
      }
   ],
   entityMap: {
      {
         0: {
            data: {
               url: "www.google.com",
               mutability: "MUTABLE",
               type: "LINK"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

**update**

use draftjs and set to readonly mode

**original answer**

[convertFromRaw](https://facebook.github.io/draft-js/docs/api-reference-data-conversion.html#content) and `EditorState.createWithContent(state),`

Comment: i'm sorry don't clarify enough that i want to show this content in some other component like article for example but not in <Editor />

Comment: It's free for you to use the json or convert to any format you want.

Comment: but how can i render json object in any of my app page? I have found this https://github.com/lokiuz/redraft modul1. In this example http://lokiuz.github.io/redraft/ u can view what i meant

Comment: you need check draftjs docs and find out the meanings of the json. basically a paragraph is a `block`, `inlineStyleRanges` is the css styles of the text in that block, `entityMap` is some meta datato the `entityRanges`.

Comment: this is not answer on question at ll

Comment: There is no sence to use another react component (like github.com/lokiuz/redraft) for rendering. Draft.js is a react component and it can be in read only mode.